# Computing Two-point correlation functions and the 'Quantum Loop Topography' ML method

Tags: condensed-matter, correlation-functions, topological-insulators

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01518.pdf) paper by Y. Zhang and E-A. Kim, the authors have designed a novel pre-processing step for machine learning topological classification.
The gist of the paper is that the authors compute chained products of correlation functions between the vertices of a triangle generating 'quantum loops'.  By this method they're able to vastly reduce the input data required for a simple neural network.

I've been working on a project to recreate the system used and as a non-expert with only a math background I've had my share of difficulty understanding the explicit computations being performed.

For the QLT computation:

> ...the relevant response function is the Hall conductivity. Interestingly
> Kitaev [35] pointed out that
> $$σ_{xy} = \frac{e^2}{h}·\frac{1}{N}\sum4πiP_{jk}P_{kl}P_{lj}S_{△jkl}  ~~~~~~~~~~  (1)$$
> for free fermion systems[36], where $P_{ij} ≡ \langle c^†_ic_j \rangle$ is the
> equal-time two-point correlation functions between site i
> and site j, S_{△jkl} is the signed area of the triangle $jkl$,
> and N is the total number of sites. Taking hints from
> Eq. (1) we use triangular loops to define QLT for Chern
> insulators. But instead of the full expectation value for
> two-point correlation functions in Eq. (1) which are costly
> to evaluate (requiring many instances of Monte Carlo
> walking down the Markov chain), we evaluate the bilinear operator with a single Monte Carlo sample defining
> $\tilde P_{jk}|_α ≡ \langle c_jc_k\rangle_α$
> for a particular Monte Carlo sample α.

I'll update this post further if this gains any traction.  And once again I must stress that I'm a beginner who has been learning their way to be able to understand this paper.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you emphasize what the actual question or confusion is